# Type 'Observable<HttpResponse<Response>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'. Type 'HttpResponse<SenderResponse>

Tags: angular, typescript

Simple call to api using HttpClient but stuck with this error

`Type 'Observable<HttpResponse<Response>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'.   Type 'HttpResponse<Response>`

Service Code :

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

getResponse(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Response>(this.url); 
  }
```

Version : Angular v10.2.3

httpClient.get should be cast to Response instead of HttpResponse. How to get the response in subscription ?

Comment: Can you show more? Such as what exactly is httpClient (did you override it)?

Comment: @BojanKogoj its HttpClient from @angular/common/http

Comment: Interesting. You would get `Observable<HttpResponse<Response>>` when putting `observe: "response"` in the options. Didn't you?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ietbpo?file=src/app/api.service.ts). What is Response in your case? Is it [Fetch API Response Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) or something else?

Comment: Your angular version is 10.2.4 which works fine. The issue is with Angular v10.2.3.